# Text column copied from Excel does not paste correctly into WPF TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a simple WPF application with an empty TextBox.  I would like the user to be able to copy rows of text (from one column) in Excel and paste the contents into the TextBox.  My app will then format the text in a certain way.

When I paste the copied rows, the TextBox only contains the *first* row.
[image: WPF app with pasted rows]

When I paste into Notepad all the items are pasted correctly. 
[image: Rows pasted into Notepad with correct formatting]

**How can I get the same effect in my WPF app?**

I have tried changing `TextWrapping` to `NoWrap`, `Wrap`, `WrapWithOverflow`. `MaxLines` is set to 2147483647.  I don’t see any other Properties that make sense to change.

Comment: No, you should mark the answer below as correct to show that you've been helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you set the `AcceptsReturn` property of the `TextBox` to `true`:

```
<TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" Height="100" />
```